# Implementar o controle de Acesso por Filtro - JSP

Tags: jsp

Podem me ajudar a implementar um controle de acesso por filtro em java?

Esta foi a implementação que eu tentei fazer até o momento, mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            String uri = req.getRequestURI();
            String usuario = getUsuario(req);


            if((usuario != null) 
                    ||(req.getRequestURI().endsWith("/WEB-INF/adm.jsp")) 
                    ||(req.getRequestURI().endsWith("/WEB-INF/alterar.jsp"))){
                }else{
                    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
            }


            chain.doFilter(request, response);  
    }

    private String getUsuario(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) req.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioLogado");                
        if(usuario==null) 
                    return "<deslogado>";
        return usuario.getUsuario();
    }
```

---

meu filter esta configurado da seguinte forma:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        String usuario = getUsuario(req);


        if((usuario != null)||(req.getRequestURI().endsWith("/adm.jsp"))){
        }else{
                req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        System.out.println("Usuario " + usuario + " acessando a URI " + uri);

        /**eliminando o cache dos formularios*/
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
        chain.doFilter(request, response);  
}

private String getUsuario(HttpServletRequest req) {
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario) req.getSession().getAttribute("usuarioLogado");                
    if(usuario==null) 
                return "<deslogado>";
    return usuario.getUsuario();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente você tem colocar a anotação na classe ou configurar o filtro no web.xml, lembrado também que a classe tem implementar a interface Filter e consequentemente os métodos init() destroy() e doFilter().

exemplo de configuração no web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>meuFiltro</filter-name>
    <filter-class>nome.do.pacote.da.classe.nomeDaClasse</filter-class>
 </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>meuFiltro</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

atráves de anotação seria mais ou menos assim, no caso de optar pelo xml a implemtação da Classe será a mesma, só precisa retirar a anotação @WebFilter

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();

        if(session.getAttribute("logado") != null){
              chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("usuario") != null
            && request.getParameter("senha") != null 
            &&  ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString().equals("URL_DA_SUA_SERVLET_DE_AUTENTICACAO")){     
             chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else{
             ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("SUA_PAGINA_DE_LOGIN");
             return;
         }  
    }


    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

A anotação @webFilter("/*") já diz que irá filtrar tudo.
  Após isso é verificado se existe o atributo logado na sessão(isso deve ser implementado na validação do Login, assim como no Logout deve se destruir a sessão), Se existir é porque existe um usuário autenticado fazendo a requisição então deixamos o passar pela porta. Se esse não for o caso então é verificado se existe os parâmetros usuário e senha e se a requisição é destinada a servlet de autenticação se essas três condição forem verdadeiras também deixamos a requisição passar pela porta, qualquer coisa fora disso é redireciona para a tela de login.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Boa tardem ajudou muito, mas meu filter já esta configurado, a dificuldade é ao dar um return após ter deslogado, e ainda ter acesso ao conteudo.

Comment: Você está invalidando a sessão no logout?

Comment: a validação esta ok, o problema é que consigo acessar depois de deslogar

Comment: Posta o código em que você faz o logout.

Comment: Bom dia Nelson,
postei o metodo Dofilter., se precisar de algo me fala.
muito obrigado.

Comment: o Codigo do Logout ficou desta forma:

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("usuarioLogado");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

Comment: Então quando você faz um logout o correto seria invalidar a sessão através  do método session.invalidate();  tenta substituir a a linha onde você remove o atributo por HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); session.invalidate(); E veja se funciona.